# iOS Silent push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

In my app I send silent push notifications to make the app download some data. This only needs to be done when the app is active, I do not want the app to start up in the background and do this.

My notification uses the:

```
aps":{"content-available" : 1 }
```

So it won't be broadcasted when the app isn't running. Since iOS 10/11 (not sure) I do not receive the silent notification in:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

So I checked the documentation and saw it was deprecated with the following message:

> NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0, 10_0, "Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:] or -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:] for user visible notifications and -[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:] for silent remote notifications");

So now I'm using `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]`, but in my console I see this warning:

> You've implemented -[ application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.

But I do not want this, since I do not want to startup in the background? Any advice how to tackle this problem.

Comment: So Basically you want to perform some action when you get a notification in foreground right!!

Comment: @anandprakash Yes

Comment: I don't believe you have an option. You will receive the notification when your app is in the background. You can simply check whether the app is in the background in the delegate method and do nothing.

Comment: So for the foreground you receive push in method -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{

 completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

Comment: you can perform your foreground task here by getting data from payload.